# Can you lose loot on the ground that is too far away for your pet to auto-loot?

Tags: lost-ark

After playing Lost Ark for a bit, every player on EU/NA receives a free pet, and one of its functions is auto looting. I usually run Chaos Dungeons with abilities that hit enemies off-screen and in the faraway distance and developed a habit of running back and forth — in case my pet doesn't auto-loot those far away items. I especially became cautious due to the warning that any uncollected loot will be lost when you leave the Chaos Dungeon. I might be wasting my time doing this, so will your pet just auto-loot everything from mobs that you kill, or can you lose loot that is off-screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pet is not in range to pick it up then yes, the loot is lost. There is no "loot recovery" features in Lost Ark. you pick it up or you lose it.